# Regex to change format of all img src attributes

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have a string contaning HTML markup with many img tags that look like this:

```
<img src="data/images/original/3.png" alt="" />
```

I need a regular expression that would change all images to have paths like this:

```
<img src="/utils/locate-image?path=data%2Fmedia%2Fimages%2Foriginal%2F3.png" alt="" />
```

I'm not very good with regular expression so I would appreciate some code example that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions for this. The [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) parser should be perfect for the job.

It should be as easy as this:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $e) {
  $e->src = "insert modified src here";
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: But won't it be slower with HTML DOM?

Comment: That would be `$e->src = '/utils/locate-image?path=' . urlencode($e->src);` is guess.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use regular expressions for this. [PHP's native DOM parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) should be perfect for the job.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<img src="foo" alt=""/>');
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($images as $image) {
    $image->setAttribute('src', 'bar');
    echo $dom->saveXML($image);
}
```

echoes `<img src="bar" alt=""/>`

Comment: +1 (despite blatant copyright violations in the 1st paragraph! :) because it doesn't require an external library.

Comment: can you say *"Abmahnung"*? :D

Comment: @Pekka cant hear you lalalalalalala ;)