# php regexp for get images

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to change format of all img src attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131691/regex-to-change-format-of-all-img-src-attributes)

Hi,

I want to replace the image path in my content db field.

I have the following

```
preg_replace("/src='(?:[^'\/]*\/)*([^']+)'/g","src='newPath/$2'",$content);
```

which is working fine for

```
src="/path/path/image.jpg"
```

BUT fails ON

```
src="http://www.mydomain.com/path/path/image.jpg"
```

Any help to bypass this problem?

Comment: `http:://` should be `http://`

Comment: I would say it generally fails for attribute values wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions for this. Use a HTML parser like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/sourcepage.html');

foreach($html->find('img') as $element)  
 {      
    $new_src = "Do stuff with new src here"; 
    $element->src = $new_src;
 }

 echo $html; // Output new code
```

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives that actually use DOM instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: Thank job is done very easily!!!!